# BufferedImage drawString corrupted letters

Tags: kotlin, bufferedimage

I'm writing a program in Kotlin to run on Raspberry Pi. I'm using a small 128x64 pixel OLED display

To display a text I'm drawing it on BufferedImage and then display that image

```
 val bufferedImage = BufferedImage(128, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
 val g = bufferedImage.createGraphics()
 g.paint = Color.WHITE
 g.font = Font("PixelMix", Font.BOLD, /*Font size*/8)
 g.drawString("IP: 192.168.1.12", 0, 24)
 g.dispose()

 display.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0)
```

link to font: https://www.dafont.com/pixelmix.font

Because screen space is very limited I use small font.

But here comes the problem - following code produces image in which the first `1` lack vertical line, while last `1` is a square.

When I do `g.font = Font("PixelMix", Font.PLAIN, 10)` then `2` in `192` lacks right-most pixel row, similarly with font size 12. On font size 16 `P` lacks vertical line and so on. It is just at font size 24 when everything looks acceptable, but 24 is way too big for a screen of that size.

My question now is how do I draw a string on BufferedImage so that I don't get artifacts like that?

**EDIT:**

At font size 10 exactly 8 pixels (vertically) are used to display a character
As for font size 8 it's 6 pixels vertically and for 16 it's 12 pixels

I did `g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF)`, but it did not helped

Comment: out of 64 vertical pixels in the display, for your font size 10, how many vertical pixels are used to print the characters (say `1`)?

Comment: From the page you linked to I see: `Use at 6pt, (or multiples of 6pt), anti-aliasing off` ` I don't know anything about fonts but I would guess that if you have a problem with the font  you would need to contact the developer.

Comment: @camickr disabling anti-aliasing does not help. And that problem is on all fonts - Minecraft, Sans, Arial etc. No matter if it's a "pixelized" font or not

Comment: `And that problem is on all fonts` - then that should be the key part of your question. Now because you include the custom Font it looks like that is where your problem is. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. The "MCVE" should use standard fonts so people on different platforms can test the code (if they wish). Maybe the problem is your platform.

Comment: @camickr With all due respect - pixel fonts are better suited for low-pixel images - if that problem were not to appear on some fonts it would be one of those. `PixelMix` is one I happened to use. I also happened to use bold font, but it's also true with plain, typeface and I assume italic. More over - if it was an issue with font then somewhere I would written it's font specific. It was not, so I see now reason why you would assume it would. Unless MCVE requires me to tell every detail that does not change the outcome.

Comment: @Miku, `You can lead a horse to water, but you can't force it to drink`. I gave my suggestions on how to improve your question to get a better answer. What you choose to do with those suggestions now and in the future is up to you.

Comment: I think there are some confusion here: *"pixel fonts are better suited for low-pixel images"*. I think what you want is a **bitmapped** font. However, what you are using, is a TrueType font, that *is designed to look pixelized in larger sizes*. Which is kind of the opposite. That said, on my system (Windows), the font looks fine in sizes 8, 16 and 24 (multiples of 8), like you write in the edit, and unlike what the author says ("multiples of 6"). Perhaps a difference between a Java 2D "point" and a Windows "point"?